# Ideal Server Deployment for Windows Server 2019 Active Directory, File Server, and SQL Server

Tags: active-directory, sql-server, hyper-v, deployment, windows-server-2019

So, we have new compliance regulations we're being required to meet and our current infrastructure isn't quite good enough to handle it.

What we need is:
2 x Active Directory Domain Controllers, DNS, DHCP (Failover, and everyone seems to recommend it)
2 x File Servers (Clustering for Failover)
2 x SQL Servers (Clustering for Failover)

Now, what is the ideal deployment to meet all these requirements?

We are currently serving 50 - 60 Computers with 30 Users.

I would prefer to keep the costs down as much as possible however most of the stuff I read states that each role really should be on it's own.

That brings the question:
Would it be possible to get two (2) servers with Windows Server 2019 Standard, install Hyper-V, Setup Hyper-V Clustering, and then run the services I need in virtual machines on those? I'm guessing the answer is probably no since the network wouldn't work without the DHCP and DNS servers but I'm wondering if there's a simple answer I'm missing.

Also, I can't help but think I'm missing something we might need for future expansion...

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
I now realize I was overthinking the problem and that I was actually on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be possible to get two (2) servers with Windows Server 2019
> Standard, install Hyper-V, Setup Hyper-V Clustering, and then run the
> services I need in virtual machines on those?

Yes, it's possible, and common. Companies all over the world have done this.

> I'm guessing the answer
> is probably no since the network wouldn't work without the DHCP and
> DNS servers but I'm wondering if there's a simple answer I'm missing.

Again, this has been done many times by many companies. I'm not sure what your actual concerns regarding DHCP and DNS are? How do you see virtual DHCP and DNS servers as being somehow different than their physical counterparts?

> Also, I can't help but think I'm missing something we might need for
> future expansion...

Again, I'm not understanding your actual concern. If you need more capacity in the future then you simply add additional Hyper-V hosts to the failover cluster.

Comment: This is one of those facepalm moments where I was overthinking things. My concerns regarding DHCP and DNS were completely unfounded because I wasn't taking into concern the failover aspect of the cluster. My bad... thank you for helping me refocus... now I can't actually believe I thought there would be a problem...

Comment: Glad to help...